# making a post request inside mapDispatchToProps in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to make a post request inside a function whenever i click on a button.
here is the code of the button

```
<Button onClick={handleClick}>Add to Cart</Button>
```

and here is the `handleClick funcion:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault(); 
        props.postCart(itemData.product_name, itemData.product_price);
    }
```

and here i showcase the code of `mapDispatchToProps` function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return {

        postCart: (productName, productPrice) => dispatch(postAddToCart(productName, productPrice))
    }
}
```

finally the code of `postAddToCart`:

```
export const postAddToCart = (productName, productPrice) => {

    const email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');

    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(productName, productPrice);
        //REST API endpoint
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/add-to-cart', {

            email:email, 
            
        })
        .then(resp => {

            dispatch({

                type: actionTypes.ADDED_TO_CART, 
                status: resp.status
            });
        })

        .catch(resp => {

            dispatch({

                type: actionTypes.ADDED_TO_CART, 
                status: "FAILED"
            });
        })

    }

}
```

But whenever i click the button Add to cart i get the following error:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`
knowing that i'm using the `redux-thunk` middleware.

Can you please tell me what's the problem and how can i fix it ? thank you ^^. if i missed something tell me in comments to add it ^^

Comment: Did you use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware?

Comment: yes i used it  @slideshowp2

Answer (score 0):

Your function `postAddToCart()` returns a "dispatcher", i.e. a function that expects `dispatch` as an argument.

The error is that you are trying to dispatch this "dispatcher", instead of an "action":

```
// wrong: calling 'dispatch()'
postCart: (productName, productPrice) => dispatch(postAddToCart( ... ))

// correct: calling the returned dispatcher and pass 'dispatch' as argument
postCart: (productName, productPrice) => postAddToCart( ... )(dispatch)
```

Comment: i still have the same problem

Comment: And the line `dispatch(productName, productPrice);` is wrong. I don't know what that was supposed to do, but the argument for `dispatch` can only be an "action", like `{ type: 'MY_ACTION_NAME', somePayload: 'some value' }`.